# Structuring a map to pass to a function which will destructure it

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to find a way to build up a parameter to pass to this function (which is part of pallet):

```
(defn node-spec [& {:keys [image hardware location network qos] :as options}]
  {:pre [(or (nil? image) (map? image))]}
  options)
```

What works is this kind of usage :

```
(node-spec :location {:location-id "eu-west-1a"}, :image {:image-id "eu-west-1/ami-937474e7"} :network {})
```

but the :location and :image bits of this are common to all machines I want to provision whereas the :network {} bit is different for each node. So I want to factor the common bit out and do something like this:

```
(def my-common-location-and-image {:location {:location-id "eu-west-1a"}, :image {:image-id "eu-west-1/ami-937474e7"}} )
(node-spec (merge {:network {:security-groups [ "group1" ] }} my-common-location-and-image ))
(node-spec (merge {:network {:security-groups [ "group1" ] }} my-common-location-and-image ))
```

but this doesn't work. The merged map is parsed as a single key missing its value. So I tried

```
(node-spec :keys (merge {:network {:security-groups [ "group1" ] }} my-common-location-and-image ))
```

and

```
(node-spec :options (merge {:network {:security-groups [ "group1" ] }} my-common-location-and-image ))
```

but that doesn't work either. I feel like I'm trying to reverse or get past the destructuring in the node-spec parameters. What am I doing wrong? Or is my goal of factoring out some of the key/value pairs impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `node-spec` function is expecting a sequence rather than a map. This is because what gets destructured is a sequence of things that can be grouped in key-value pairs.

So, instead of passing this:

```
{:image {:image-id "eu-west-1/ami-937474e7"}, :location {:location-id "eu-west-1a"}, :network {:security-groups ["group1"]}}
```

We need to pass this:

```
'(:image {:image-id "eu-west-1/ami-937474e7"} :location {:location-id "eu-west-1a"} :network {:security-groups ["group1"]})
```

Which means that this will work:

```
(apply node-spec
       (reduce concat
               (merge {:network {:security-groups ["group1"]}}
                      my-common-location-and-image)))
```

Comment: Yes, your point about expecting a sequence is what I was missing I think. But (concat {:k "value"}) produces ([{:k "value"}]) which isn't quite there yet?

Comment: `(concat {:k "value"})` and  `(apply concat {:k "value"})` have very different effects - try it out in the REPL to see what I mean. I could just have easily written `(reduce concat {:k "value"})` - perhaps that would make it clearer (yields the same result).

Comment: Okay, I've changed `apply concat` to `reduce concat` for clarity of intent - but the effect is the same.

Comment: I see what you mean. ta, Chris